# Navigation Component how to make each fragment only has one instance all the time

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, bottomnavigationview

My project

- Single activity pattern with fragments in kotlin.
- `Navigation component` + `bottom navigation view` together.
- There are four tabs(fragments) in bottom navigation view.

My issue is changing each tab in bottom navigation, then each fragment is re-created which due to the app is laggy.

So my target is **making only one instance of each fragment there.**

What I tried is:

1. adding `app:launchSingleTop="true"` for the tab fragment in `grap.xml`. **DOESN'T WORK.**
2. This idea is if the tab fragment can be pop backed then use it directly or create new. But this only works sometimes. Some times the tab fragment does not re-created but some times are!

   I think the reason is pop back stack clear it for some time? Not sure.

   ```
   binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item: MenuItem ->

         if (!navController.popBackStack(item.itemId, false)) {
             NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item , navController)

         }
         true
     }
   ```
3. I used `navController.navigate(item.itemId, null, NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(item.itemId, false).build())` to replace `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item , navController)`, still doesn't work.

Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

just add this piece of code to avoid recreation

```
binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemReselectedListener { }
```

Comment: Thanks, Tried it, it still doesn't work.